# What is the best way to integrate an external build tool into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, waf

I've just started using Eclipse for Python development since we can make use of a lovely plugin I've found to enable distributed pair-programming.  Anyway, the next step to getting Eclipse to integrate properly with our existing environment, would be finding a way to drive our current build tool ([Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/)) from within the IDE.

So the question is, is there a way I can set up Eclipse to drive Waf in a `Make`-like fashion?  I see for `Make` it has some quite advanced functionality, such as being able to work out what targets are available etc.  Bonus points for telling me if there is a way I could go as far as this! (I suspect the answer is that this is all built in to the Make plugin for Ecplipse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and define a **[Custom builder](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html)**, calling Waf with the appropriate options for the python compilation step.

[image: http://nmake.alcatel-lucent.com/manual/eclipse/jdt_lu38/builders.png]

<sup>(From [eclipsejdt alcatel-lucent manual](http://nmake.alcatel-lucent.com/manual/eclipsejdt.html))</sup>

That picture (not related to Waf at all) illustrates the fact a builder can be defined as an external tool (meaning any `.bat` or shell you may want to call)

In that "[eclipsejdt](http://nmake.alcatel-lucent.com/manual/eclipsejdt.html)" example, the custom builder was configured like so:

> To set up the builder, bring up the property dialog for project "`jex1p`" by selecting the project in the Package Explorer and selecting **`Project > Properties > Builders`**.   Then click `New...`, select `Program`, and click `OK`.
>
> Configure the builder Main tab using values:

```
Name             : nmbldr_pre
Location         : ${system_path:ksh}
Working Directory: ${build_project}
Arguments        : nmbldr -p 2 -t ${build_type} -s jpre
```

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse CDT I run waf by simply changing the build program in
ProjectPreferences->C/C++ Build->BuilderSettings
Choose External builder and then put in the path to waf

for example I use 
    /Users/mark/bin/waf -v -k -j2

Note that waf and make do not agree on the -j setting and you have to give i explicitly and not use the eclipse dialog.

You can use the Make targets view add the targets to call waf e.g. configure, build etc.

One issue I had is that Eclipse is hard coded to see the output from Make say Make when i changes directory so I had to patch waf 
see [waf issue](http://code.google.com/p/waf/issues/detail?id=366&can=1&q=eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

As VonC says, the elegant way is to use a [Custom builder](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html).

Alternatively it is less work (in the short term) to hack together an ant script to do the heavy lifting and define an [external builder](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) to configure it onto the project. You may find the drawbacks of an external builder (e.g. no incremental support) mean it is worth investing the effort to do it "properly".